# Django Delete a many to many field

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, many-to-many

I have 2 models *User* which is Django's auth_user, and *HostCourse* which has a many to many relationship with User

```
class HostCourse(TimeStamped, models.Model):
    created_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
    ...
```

I am using Postgresql, and I am trying to delete the data in *HostCourse* from dbshell.

```
delete from courses_hostcourse;
```

When I delete some data from *HostCourse*, it throws the following error:

`ERROR:  update or delete on table "courses_hostcourse" violates foreign key constraint "courses_hostcourse_c_hostcourse_id_ec1070c3_fk_courses_h" on table "courses_hostcourse_created_by"`

If I'll include `on_delete=models.CASCASE`, will it also delete the users of the respective *HostCourse*? If yes, how can I find a workaround, so that it deletes courses and not users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well usually you would do it in the python shell like this:

```
./manage.py shell
>>> HostCourse.objects.all().delete()
```

ManyToManyField creates a new table, so you want to delete all objects there first. The users won't be deleted
In the db_shell you would do:

```
delete from courses_hostcourse_created_by;
delete from courses_hostcourse;
```